# Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS: Realtek Wifi adapter RTL8723DE HP laptop WIFI SIGNALS TOO WEAK

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, realtek-wireless

I installed 18.0.4 LTS as well as rtl8723de drivers

The drivers work only when the wifi device is just close to the laptop..

When the wifi device is even slightly away the laptop cannot connect to the wifi device and errors ut saying "Connection Failed Activation of Network Connection failed"

Another laptop with Windows OS right next to this Ubuntu loaded laptop works fine and connects to the same wifi with 'full' signal strength

I called HP Technical support - HP declined to provide any driver support on laptops loaded with anything other than Windows.

Please help what should I do in order to make my new laptops work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also got myself an HP Laptop, and had to install the driver, and configure `ant_sel=2`, don't forget that the wifi card is a **single band** so it will be slower, try a speed test on your Ubuntu and Windows machines to see whether they have different network speeds.
 as the_mighty420 answered, remember to `echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf` so the configuration will stay on `ant_sel=2` after you reboot.
Just a pointer (if you are a noob like me) write down the commands you ran to install the driver, as you will need to reinstall it after every new linux kernel update.

Comment: Just install once using dkms and don't worry about kernel updates

Comment: Thank you for the timely answer and caution - I'll keep these commands safe to repeat them later.

Comment: @Jeremy31, being that I am a noob, I will appreciate if you can post an answer how to install it using dkms